# Azure B2C check user exist or not?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure B2C, followed by the article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

User is added successfully. But the issue is how to check the user exist or not with a user name, when I creating a new user?

Comment: Pretty sure you would get an error in that case? :) Best way in my opinion would be to handle that error rather than checking and then creating, introducing a race condition into the code.

Comment: Got error "StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'," How to get a user with particular username ?

Comment: /users/first.last@company.com :)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried   var payload = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.windows.net /************.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6/username.onmicrosoft.com"); got error "StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'," Is any mistake?

Comment: I meant `graph.windows.net /************.onmicrosoft.com/users/username.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find users by their email address or their user name using the `signInNames` filter.

For an email address:

```
`GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value eq 'someone@somewhere.com')&api-version=1.6`
```

For a user name:

```
`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value eq 'someone')&api-version=1.6`
```

Comment: Actually it return success, but when I tried which exist or not exist username, it return same.

Comment: In both cases, Azure AD Graph API returns 200 OK. If the sign-in name does exist, then a non-empty array, containing the matched user, is returned. If the sign-in name doesn't exist, then an empty array is returned.

Comment: I am getting "{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_InvalidDataContractVersion","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The specified api-version is invalid. The value must exactly match a supported version."}}}" .. Can you help please? @ChrisPadgett

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, to check the user with the email address already exist.
here is a solution using C# and Graph client library.

```
private async Task<User> CheckUserAlreadyExistAsync(string email, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var filter = $"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{email}' and c/issuer eq '{email}')";

        var request = _graphServiceClient.Users.Request()
            .Filter(filter)
            .Select(userSelectQuery)
            .Expand(e => e.AppRoleAssignments);

        var userCollectionPage = await request.GetAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return userCollectionPage.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```