# Azure B2C check user email Id exists or not using Graph in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-3.1

Referring to [Azure B2C check user exist or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288877/azure-b2c-check-user-exist-or-not/66056883#66056883) I am facing an issue while trying to check if user emailId exists in B2C. Below is the code which I referred to implement from the above mention stackoverflow link where @Saurab Kulkarni suggested the approach, which is close to my requirement, but it always return Status= AwaitingForActivation. Could you please help?

```
    public interface IGraphHelper
    {
    Task<User> CheckUserByEmailId(string email, CancellationToken ct); 
    }

    public class GraphHelper : IGraphHelper
    {
    private readonly ADOptions _adOptions;

    public async Task<User> CheckUserByEmailId(string email, CancellationToken ct)
    {
    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = 
                                    ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder 
                                          .Create(_adOptions.ClientId)     
                                            .WithTenantId(_adOptions.TenantId)
                                            .WithClientSecret(_adOptions.ClientSecret)
                                               .Build();

        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new 
                              ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    var filter = $"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{email}' and c/issuer eq '{_adOptions.Issuer}')";

    var request = graphClient.Users.Request()
            .Filter(filter)
               .Select(userSelectQuery)   //What is userSelectQuery here? 
            .Expand(e => e.AppRoleAssignments);

        var userCollectionPage = await request.GetAsync(ct);

        return userCollectionPage.FirstOrDefault();
```

}
}

```
    //Home Controller//

    public JsonResult CheckName(string emailId, CancellationToken ct)
    { 
        string email = emailId;
        bool status;
        var result = _graphHelper.CheckUserByEmailId(email, ct);
        return Json(status);
    }`

    Error:
```

=================================

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Always returns: Status: Waiting for Activation.

Comment: That kinda looks like a `Task` to me that you are looking at. Maybe you haven't `await`ed the Task?

Comment: @juunas- Thanks for your response. Here i am awaiting the Task in the above code
 var userCollectionPage = await request.GetAsync(ct);

Comment: Yes but you are not awaiting the function in the controller.

Comment: Thanks @juunas for suggestion. I could make it work after making appropriate changes to the way of calling Task and now it works fine. Thanks once again!

Comment: Here is some more options to resolve the waitingforactivation error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551008/task-keeps-waiting-for-activation

Comment: @Rishi Did you mean 'public async Task<JsonResult> CheckName(string emailId, CancellationToken ct)' sir?

Answer (score 0):

Tiny and Daniel Mann pointed out the direction, you need to make your event handler `async` as well:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> CheckName(string emailId, CancellationToken ct) { 
       
        string email = emailId;
        bool status;
        var result = _graphHelper.CheckUserByEmailId(email, ct);
        return Json(status);
    }
```