# How to verify Microsoft email account from Azure REST API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-rest-api

I have a requirement to verify the genuine Microsoft email address from REST API from my project.  I have implemented the Azure B2c Active directory but before users signs in to their account. I need to capture & validate the User's Microsoft account from our existing system using REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the user exists, you could use Microsoft Graph API, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52289249/13308381).

If you want to check your account and password, you could use [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow)(resource owner password credentials) flow.

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token

username=<user-account>
&password=<Passxword1>
&grant_type=password
&scope=openid <application-id> offline_access
&client_id=<application-id>
&response_type=token+id_token
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.